# amcharts 4: Removing side padding on graphic starting point

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have a charts which doesn't start exacly at 0.

Here is my chart with a sample data

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.dataSource.url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/109xmw";
chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function(ev) {
    var data = ev.target.data;
    data.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
        return lhs.time - rhs.time;
    });
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        item.time *= 1000;
    });
});

chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.0b";
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "x";
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("minute", "d MMM, \nHH:mm");
dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("minute", "d MMM, \nHH:mm");

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "time";
series.name = "Traffic out";
series.dataFields.valueY = "outDiffFormatted";
series.tooltipHTML = "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}/s</b></span>";
series.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.stacked = false;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.dataFields.dateX = "time";
series2.name = "Traffic in";
series2.dataFields.valueY = "inDiffFormatted";
series2.tooltipHTML = "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}/s</b></span>";
series2.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series2.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series2.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series2.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series2.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series2.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series2.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series2.stacked = false;
series2.strokeWidth = 2;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "top";
```

```css
body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
#chartdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

I don't understand why I have this white space.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;` and `dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;`, it means that half of the first and half of the last cell is shown, making the series extend right to the edge of the plot area.

More about it: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/positioning-axis-elements/

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.dataSource.url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/109xmw";
chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function(ev) {
    var data = ev.target.data;
    data.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
        return lhs.time - rhs.time;
    });
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        item.time *= 1000;
    });
});

chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.0b";
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "x";
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("minute", "d MMM, \nHH:mm");
dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("minute", "d MMM, \nHH:mm");
dateAxis.startLocation = 0.5;
dateAxis.endLocation = 0.5;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "time";
series.name = "Traffic out";
series.dataFields.valueY = "outDiffFormatted";
series.tooltipHTML = "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}/s</b></span>";
series.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series.fillOpacity = 0.6;
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.stacked = false;

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.dataFields.dateX = "time";
series2.name = "Traffic in";
series2.dataFields.valueY = "inDiffFormatted";
series2.tooltipHTML = "<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>{valueY.value}/s</b></span>";
series2.tooltipText = "[#000]{valueY.value}[/]";
series2.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#FFF");
series2.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
series2.tooltip.getStrokeFromObject = true;
series2.tooltip.background.strokeWidth = 3;
series2.sequencedInterpolation = true;
series2.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series2.stacked = false;
series2.strokeWidth = 2;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "top";
```

```css
body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
#chartdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force it by setting strictMinMax to true for each valueAxis where you want your minimum enforced (of course, you have to make sure you're setting minimum in each value axis).
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minimum

Comment: How do I specify it ? The doc you gave me is for amcharts3, I'm using amcharts4